# MySql bat script to load xml tables error

Tags: mysql, windows

I've used this script in my other computer but for some reason it's not working here:

C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -p  bdlogs < insereLogs.sql

del C:\xampp\mysql\scripts*.xml

pause

Though for some odd reason it's not working on my friend's computer, this is the message I get:

Command Prompt Error 'C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that the mysql executable can't be found on the specified location (c:\xamp\mysql).

I guess there is no mysql installed on your friend's computer or it is installed in a different directory.